# How can I check if the first character of my string is a space or tab character?

Tags: c#

I asked a question about removing spaces and tabs. Now I have something else needed. I need to be able to check if the first character of a string is a space or tab. Can anyone think of a good way to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: just a space or tab, or any whitespace?

Comment: a space or tab. What other kind of whitespace are there?

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode

Comment: @Jason, Daniel Hilgarth, as we can see from the good link, there are lots of whitespace chars especially once you consider the range "U+2000–U+200A (different sorts of spaces)". There may also be other non printing charachters you might want to consider.

Answer (score 16):

The best way is to use the [`Char.IsWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1x308yk8.aspx) method:

```
// Normally, you would also want to check that the input is valid (e.g. not null)
var input = "blah";

var startsWithWhiteSpace = char.IsWhiteSpace(input, 0); // 0 = first character
if (startsWithWhiteSpace)
{
    // your code here
}
```

The method's documentation explicitly mentions what exactly is considered white space; if for some reason that list of characters does not suit your needs, you will have to do a more restrictive check manually.

Comment: You can also use `char.IsWhiteSpace(input[0])`

Comment: Try it with `input = ""`... ;)

Comment: You should be checking if the string is not null or empty. See my answer

Comment: I don't think such a trivial example needs explicit error-checking.

Comment: It sure needs. Never trust input!

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: The *application* needs to have validation, sure. The example (at least IMHO), not necessarily.

Comment: @Jon: I agree with you that examples should be simple, but the code you - and many others - posted will fail with a runtime exception if the string is null or empty. This check belongs exactly there and not at some other place in the application, so I say it is an integral part of this code and should be provided, otherwise the OP might not be aware of this pitfall. Especially as it might well be that `IsWhiteSpace` just returns false on an empty string - which it doesn't, but reading your code it can be assumed.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: I agree that this is where the check belongs, yes. But the check has nothing to do with the question asked, even if it *would* be a must for a production app. Also, what would the check do if it detects invalid input? Throw an exception? That's what you want to avoid. Silently execute (or not execute) the branch? That is a business logic decision, which (especially in the general case) we do not have enough context to make. For these and other reasons, I prefer to not include error checking in simple illustrative examples.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2843/discussion-between-jon-and-daniel-hilgarth)

Answer (score 6):

You can check it like this:

```
if( myString[0] == ' ' || myString[0] == '\t' ){
  //do your thing here
}
```

This will fail for emtpy and null strings, so you should probably make it a bit more secure like this:

```
if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString) && (myString[0] == ' ' || myString[0] == '\t') ){
  //do your thing here
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would just go with something like:

```
if (str.StartsWith(" ") || str.StartsWith("\t")) {
    ...
}
```

or:

```
if ((str[0] == ' ') || (str[0] == "\t")) {
    ...
}
```

I actually prefer the former since you don't have to worry about problems with empty strings.

If you want to handle more complex case in future, you could use regular expressions, something like:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch (str, @"^\s")) ...
```

This can be modified to handle arbitrarily complex cases, though it's a bit like killing flies with a thermo-nuclear warhead for your particular case.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: originally the Greek 'ειρήνη με το διάβολο', peace with the devil (more peace with the dark side of my nature) but changed because the Latin (or what _passes_ for Latin in my circles) was more succinct. It's just a nick, one I made up when there were too many people in my employment circle with the same first name as I :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you are not only interested in space and tab but in whitespace in general, use this:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myString) && char.IsWhiteSpace(myString[0]))
    // It's a whitespace
```

Answer (score 2):

And just for fun:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\s")) {
  // yep, starts with whitespace
}
```

Note that while many of the other answers will fail when given an empty string, this one will work, and it would be easily extensible to match more complex things than just whitespace at the beginning of the string. Some people find regexes to be overkill for simple checks, but others believe that if you want to do pattern matching on strings, you should use regexes.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (text[0] == ' ' || text[0] == '\t')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(myString[0]==' ' || myString[0]=='\t') 
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to have the `System.Linq` namespace imported.

```
var firstToken = yourString.FirstOrDefault();
if (firstToken == ' ' || firstToken == '\t')
{
   // First character is a space or tab
}
else
{
   // First character is not a space or tab, or string is empty.
}
```